# Why should I save oauth2 access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

When I need only grant from google for email id.Instead of saving access token. Is it better to save user details in db.

Instead saving access token and retrieving data from oauth server (google or facebook, etc.)  with Api call

Is it right method saving user information when first authentication and retrieving from database.

Comment: I am voting to close this as I am unsure what you are asking. You could try to [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Are you asking if you should save the users login username / password and use that instead of Access / Refresh tokens? No, you absolutely should not.

Comment: No saving email Id as mandatory

Comment: My mistake, you need the user ID, you _should not_ save the password.

Comment: I am not saving password i am just saving email id  when email id not exist  i will create new user in db if  exist than login with that user

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right, you must be trying to authenticate yourself with Google/Facebook and you want to consume the email id of the user from the authentication information??

It is not right to save any user related info on your database. The main purpose of delegating authentication/user management to another provider is defeated here. If you save the user info on your local DB, how would you deal with the scenario when the user updates his details on Facebook/Google? This will result in different copies and now you have to think of ways to synchronise ur database info periodically with the Oauth provider.

Please elaborate your problem statement a little more so that we can help.

Comment: Yes you are right. When user change any details that will not affect in local db. However I just want email id and user name for my project. So is there any other scenario that this method is wrong